# What exception should be thrown when validating results from external callbacks in .NET?

Tags: .net, exception

ArgumentException and ArgumentNullException are both used for validating arguments, eg.

```
if (argument == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("argument must not be null", "argument");
```

What is the best equivalent for validating the results of callbacks, eg.

```
var x = argument.GetX();
if (x == null)
    throw ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing much about your code, I can suggest throwing InvalidOperationException.

Alternatively, if this piece of code is important, you can create custom exception, say XLoadException, and throw that.

Comment: In my case an XmlException made the best sense, but it still seems like there should be a better solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use ArgumentException or ArgumentNullException in conjunction with testing parameters passed to routines, like this:

```
Public Sub Test(s As Object)

If s Is Nothing Then
  Throw New ArgumentNullException("s")
End If

End Sub
```

In your case, I would just throw a normal Exception, since the variable 'x' is not an argument passed to your routine, it's a local variable. I would recommend using ArgumentException or ArgumentNullException for parameters passed to routines rather then local variables.